# How to force WatchOS to generate app crash logs?

Tags: xcode, watchkit, watchos

I am developing an application that needs to record a lot of data, which should be sent to the iPhone later. I am using CoreData and sometimes the quantity of memory used reaches 100 MBs, and also the CPU can reach 100%. I can see this during debug, but during debug the app doesn't crash because there are no memory/CPU limits. So the problem is that every time that I use the app without debugging, it may crash every 2-3 minutes but no crash log is generated, and I can't understand why and in what line of code it crashes. Is there a way to force WatchOS generating the crash logs?

**Edit**
If at least there is a way to debug the application with real memory/CPU limits (which are nonexistent in debug mode), so that I can understand why and where it crashes, or if there is any way to make some diagnostic to understand the unexplainable crashes, please let me know.